# Django redirect in admin failed

Tags: python, django, django-admin

After saving an object by clicking *saveasnew* button in admin interface i want to redirect to another url:

```
admin.py
class AirplanesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    if "_saveasnew" in request.POST:
        self.message_user(request, 'YAY!!!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:routes_airplanes_change',
                                    args=(obj.pk,),
                                    current_app=self.admin_site.name))
```

The *"YAY"* message is showed... but django redirects me in a list of pbject pages, not to a new object page... Don't work even this code:

```
admin.py
class AirplanesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    if "_saveasnew" in request.POST:
        self.message_user(request, 'YAY!!!')
        redirect('http://example.com')
```

I see *"YAY"*, but it redirects me to a list object again... what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: you need to return redirect()

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help.
It's okay with django ? i'm using 1.5.5 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save_model` return None. and It's result is not used anywhere. So doesn't matter what is returned (`redirect(...)` or `None`)

I think

```
def response_add(self, request, new_object):
    pass
```

and

```
def response_change(self, request, new_object):
    pass
```

are what You are looking for.

If we look into django source code we will see following:

```
def response_change(self, request, obj):
    """
    Determines the HttpResponse for the change_view stage.
    """
```

and

```
def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
    """
    Determines the HttpResponse for the add_view stage.
    """
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for me... but in admin.py i need to override whole method **response_add**... is this the only way ?
I mean, why redirect didn't worked from _save_model_ method ?..

Comment: redirect didn't worked because `save_model` return `None`. and It's result is not used anywhere. and redirect result is not Exception but just Responce instance.

Comment: I see... well, the problem is solvd by overriding the **response_add** method